# Downgrade to XOrg 1.19.3 (to install AMDGPU) on Ubuntu 16.04.3

Tags: 16.04, xorg, amdgpu-pro

Trying to install AMDGPU driver for my Radeon R9 285/380 Graphics Card from here:

http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDGPU-PRO-Install.aspx

Installation goes through smoothly and is fine after restart. The Graphics card is installed, at least according to dpkg

```
dpkg -l|grep amdgpu
ii  libdrm-amdgpu1:amd64                          2.4.83-1~16.04.1                             amd64        Userspace interface to amdgpu-specific kernel DRM services -- runtime
ii  libdrm-amdgpu1:i386                           2.4.83-1~16.04.1                             i386         Userspace interface to amdgpu-specific kernel DRM services -- runtime
ii  xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu-hwe-16.04           1.3.0-0ubuntu1~16.04.1                       amd64        X.Org X server -- AMDGPU display driver
```

However, the /var/log/Xorg.0.log contains no mention of amdgpu, which means that it is not actually loaded. After contacting AMD technical support, they have informed me that the driver is extremely picky for exact version of XOrg. My current version of XOrg is 1.19.5, but the required one is 1.19.3

Comment: Hi Aleksejs, please don't even think about downgrading Xorg - it may break things badly. Also, the already installed open source `radeon` drivers are providing a better performance experience than the AMDGPU drivers ... so I recommend to use what Ubuntu delivers out-of-the-box and stick with the default drivers. :)

Comment: Not that hard to due as you'll only need to downgrade 1 or 2 packages. Best thing to do is install synaptic, search xserver & look for any xserver packages at version 2:1.19.5 ...  There *usually* will only be 1 or 2 `xserver-xorg-core-hwe-16.04` & maybe `xserver-xorg-legacy-hwe-16.04` Then download the earlier package(s), put in a folder, cd to folder & install with `sudo dpkg -i *.deb` If you missed a package dpkg will report an error. Locate the missing package, add to folder & rerun the dpkg command until it completes without error.    Link in next comment

Comment: Look here, under `Builds` section pick your Arch, on the arch page scroll down to `Built files` to find the packages you need. https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server-hwe-16.04/2:1.19.3-1ubuntu1~16.04.4 If confused at all post back before proceeding

Comment: Thanks guys. Perhaps I should reconsider. If the advantage of the AMDGPU is not significant, compared to default driver, it is probably not worth the hassle.